# Finding markers/locations within a radius on GoogleMap

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, location

I have a database that stores markers latitude and longitude. I have a class that so far has my current location and I want to be able to show all the markers within a certain radius of my current location. I access markers by doing something similar to this.

```
List <Markers> markers = db.getAllMarkers();
```

I'm not sure how to obtain the radius and check if any of my markers are within the radius. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have current location (as a center of circle) and each marker has position you can use
method `computeDistanceBetween()` from geometry library. See [spherical library docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical). It returns the distance between two LatLngs. So, if distance is less than radius, marker is in...

Note: It takes as arguments two LatLng objects and the 3rd argument is a default Earth radius.